# Form with nested models doesn't update nor give nested params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes, parameters

In rails 3.2.* I have a has_one belongs_to nested model like so:

```
class Unicycle < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :brand, :wheel, :wheel_attributes
  has_one :wheel
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :wheel
end

class Wheel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :diameter, :unicycle
  belongs_to :unicycle
end
```

My controler looks like so:

```
class UnicyclesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @unicycles = Unicycle.all
  end

  def edit
    @unicycle = Unicycle.find_by_id params[:id]
  end

  def update
    @unicycle = Unicycle.find_by_id params[:id]
    if @unicycle.update_attributes! params[:unicycle]
      redirect_to unicycles_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
end
```

And my edit.html.erb like so:

```
<%= form_for @unicycle do |formbuilder| %>
  <%= formbuilder.text_field :brand %>

  <%= fields_for @unicycle.wheel do |fieldbuilder| %>
    <%= fieldbuilder.number_field :diameter %>
  <% end %>

  <%= formbuilder.submit %>
<% end %>
```

But when I update, changes made to wheel.diameter are just silently ignored.

I've found out that even though my `fields_for` call is nested within my `form_for` block in edit.html.erb, **the params sent to my update function are not nested**.

Params contains:

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"owiV5xwbbt+ft8h4K4bIqshp5I6jrlj5XWEKeVXpoCQ=",
 "unicycle"=>{"brand"=>"Unibike"},
 "wheel"=>{"diameter"=>"70"},
 "commit"=>"Update Unicycle",
 "action"=>"update",
 "controller"=>"unicycles",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

but according to the rails documentation ([ActiveRecordNestedAttributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)) the wheel params should really be nested within unicycle like this:

```
 "unicycle"=>{"brand"=>"Unibike", "wheel"=>{"diameter"=>"68"}},
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you generate nested fields:

```
# ...
<%= formbuilder.fields_for :wheel do |fieldbuilder| %>
  <%= fieldbuilder.number_field :diameter %>
<% end %>
# ...
```

Comment: Well spotted! Works like a charm now!